# How to pass an array of strings or a string vector to an IN clause in a parameterized SQL query?

Tags: sql, informix, parameterized

I have this code in my executeQueries.ec file

```
sprintf(sqlQuery,
"select distinct e.emp_id, e.join_date \
from employees e
where e.emp_id in (?) and e.dob <= '%s')");

$prepare empDataStmt from $sqlQuery;
if (sqlca.sqlcode)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Error %d in prepare empDataStmt%s\n",
    sqlca.sqlcode, sqlQuery);
    return 0;
}
$declare empDataCursor cursor for incptDatesStmt;

if (pcs_sql_check("Error in declaring empDataCursor Stmt"))
{
    return 1;
}

$open empDataCursor using $empIds_,dob_ ;
```

When I dbx the code and print `empIds_`, I get this on console:

```
""04-Emp1","W2-Emp2""
```

Which means content of empIds_ is `"04-Emp1","W2-Emp2"`  (quotes included).
The question is that the number of `empIds` can be anything from 1 to 100 or 500.
For example it can even be:

```
"04-Emp1","W2-Emp2","04-Emp4","W2-Emp3","0A-Emp1","E2-Emp7"
```

Because of this I can not get my code to work. Can anybody help me to write this code with using "?" for parametrized query that can handle any number of `empIds`.   Please note that the content of empIds_ will always have double-quotes embedded in them. I do not know whether this is a good thing or bad but I cannot do anything to prevent it.

Comment: Generally speaking, you can't expand parameter markers like that (automatically, as parts of strings) - the RDBMS simply thinks it's all one string.  Some RDBMSs and the connection interfaces allow you to supply _arrays_ in that situation.  Otherwise: 1) you're already using dynamic SQL, just use whatever list you already have, or 2) - designate a list of 500 parameters for the statement (doable, but annoying/not really future proof).  Oh, and is `emp_id` not unique?  I wouldn't have thought you'd need `DISTINCT`...

Comment: @X-zero Thanks for the explanation...will keep in mind.

Answer (score 0):

#### A Minor Diversion

You have some syntactic problems in what you show us:

```
sprintf(sqlQuery,
"select distinct e.emp_id, e.join_date \
from employees e
where e.emp_id in (?) and e.dob <= '%s')");
```

That won't compile; you'd need a second backslash after `employees e`.  I strong recommend avoiding backslash-newline in strings; use string concatenation instead.

```
sprintf(sqlQuery, "select distinct e.emp_id, e.join_date from employees e "
                  "where e.emp_id in (?) and e.dob <= '%s')");
```

Note that there is just white space (comments would count as white space too) between the two parts of the string; the C compiler concatenates such strings into a single string.

Now the `sprintf()` call is syntactically correct at the C source level; it is still semantically incorrect because it contains `%s` and you've not provided a string for it to copy.  You should presumably be using a placeholder `?` for the date since you pass it to the `$open` statement as a second parameter (but there isn't actually a placeholder for it).

You would then be able to avoid an explicit prepare operation by writing:

```
$ DECLARE empDataCursor FOR
    SELECT DISTINCT e.emp_id, e.join_date
      FROM employees e 
     WHERE e.emp_id IN ($empIds_) AND e.dob <= $dob_;
```

---

#### The Crux

However, this isn't going to work for you, unfortunately.  The crux of your problem is you are trying to pass a string as a list of values for the IN clause.  It simply doesn't work like that.  If you have one value, you need one placeholder (`?`); if you have two values, you need two placeholders, etc.

So, we end up going back to a full prepared statement and substitute the empIds into the string:

```
 int reqlen;

 reqlen = snprintf(sqlQuery, sizeof(sqlQuery), "SELECT DISTINCT e.emp_id, e.join_date"
                       " FROM employees e WHERE  e.emp_id IN (%s) AND e.dob <= '%s'",
                       empIds_, dob_);

 if (reqlen >= sizeof(sqlQuery))
     ...truncated SQL...larger sqlQuery needed...

 $ PREPARE empDataStmt FROM $sqlQuery;
 ...SQL error check...
 $ DECLARE empDataCursor FOR empDataStmt;
 ...SQL error check...

 $ OPEN empDataCursor;   /* No USING clause! */
 ...SQL error check...

 ...code as before...
```